# Using multiple instances of Kendo PanelBar in project

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm just learning Kendo Mobile UI by building a hybrid app. At the moment I am using the Kendo PanelBar widget to make some collapsable menus within my app like so:

```
  <ul id="panelBar">
    <li class="child"><strong>What sound was that?</strong>
      <ul>
        <li><em>The sound was from a cow.</em></li>  
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#panelBar").kendoPanelBar();
    });
</script>
```

Ok, so the Panelbar is working on the first view that is called (that uses it). But if I navigate to any other views that use it - it does not render at all.

Now would this by chance have anything to do with me using the $(document).ready(function() to call it?

UPDATE: I tried using data-show="onShow" in the view div and then using the associated function to initialise the panelbar but that is not working out for me either. It seems the kendo panelbar can only be initiated once in this way.

I'm pretty sure the Kendo PanelBar is flawed when multiple instances are used within separate HTML pages.

Comment: Navigate to another view meaning different page? As long as you're calling .kendoPanelBar() on each load you should be good. Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: I get Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined. But I'm pretty sure that is in relation to Cordova Media API plugin I am using because when run in the iOS Simulator, there are no obvious issues.

Comment: Are the other views where the PanelBar breaks completely different pages with a new URL?

Comment: Yes the views are in separate HTML pages.

Comment: And the .kendoPanelBar() is called on every page?

Comment: Yes it's called on every page, just like the code I put into the question illustrates. I even tried to use .destroy() but that just broke the code completely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56959/discussion-between-ryan-coolwebs-and-andrew-walters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you have an ID assigned to the element.
Kendo UI Mobile keeps all your views in the DOM, but hides the ones that aren't visible.
This means that you will have multiple elements with the same ID, which is not valid HTML, and the jQuery selector `$("#panelBar")` will only return the first one found in the DOM, which may be on a hidden page.

You could try making the IDs distinct for each page.

---

Also, `$(document).ready()` will only be fired once when the app starts, not when each page is viewed.

---

If you aren't passing any options to the `.kendoPanelBar()` function, then you might just want to use a class instead of an ID.

```
<ul class="panelBar"> ... </ul>
<ul class="panelBar"> ... </ul>
<ul class="panelBar"> ... </ul>

$(".panelBar").kendoPanelBar();
```

---

Or use the MVVM approach and set the `data-role` on each element...

```
<ul data-role="panelbar"> ... </ul>
<ul data-role="panelbar"> ... </ul>
<ul data-role="panelbar"> ... </ul>
```

with no javascript call to .kendoPanelBar()

Comment: you friend, are a champion! I added a class to ul and kept the ID (as I have styles attached to it) and used the class instead of ID in the javascript initialisation. Plus I am now using data-show="onShow" in the view div then the appropriate js initialisation under the function instead of $(document).ready()

The MVVM approach with data-role did not work out for me. BTW, I've been to your blog and found it most helpful, keep up the good work!